# CloudFront has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I use `axios` to get a resource (md file) from my cdn (served by aws CloudFront).

I get this error message in the browser:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://next.cdn.example.com/foo/bar.md'
> from origin 'https://next.example.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource

```
My website is: https://next.example.com
My cdn: https://next.cdn.example.com
```

But in CloudFront I setup everything to support CORS (in the pictures).

What else can I do to solve this problem?

**S3**
[image]

[image]

CloudFront

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do believe you need to allow also OPTIONS request on your behavior setup of the CloudFront. OPTIONS request is sent prior to actual GET/POST request for CORS request, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Functional_overview for more details.